# Add a dropdown(submenu) to existing menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a dropdown option(submenu) to existing menu bar.

Here is my CSS and HTML code.

I found a lot of drop down menus.
But it is very important to me that, I just want to add the new function to my existing menu, without much changes to the whole menu.

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 
  <a href="#news">Speed Dial</a>
  <a href="#news">Speed Dial</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  If it's "very important to you" then surely you've made *some* effort somewhere?

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: @SarinJacobSunny, i just want to add dropdown menu to some of elements in menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to meet your requirement by modifying your own code.

Style/CSS corrections are left for you.

Try it out.

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

**Code**

```css
            .topnav {
                background-color: #333;
                height: 50px;
            }

            .topnav li {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                text-align: right;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                font-size: 17px;
                background: transparent;
                width: 150px;
            }

            .topnav li a{
                padding: 14px 16px;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .topnav li a:hover{
                background-color: #ddd;
                color: black;
            }

            .topnav li.active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
            }

            .subnav {
                background-color: blue;
                overflow: hidden;
                display : none;
                width: 200px;
                margin-top: 15px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .subnav li {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                text-align: right;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

            .subnav li a {
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .subnav li:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
                color: black;
            }

            .subnav li.active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
            }

            .topnav li:hover .subnav{
                display : block;
            }
```

```html
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li>
                <a href="#news">Main 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#news">Main 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#news">Main 3 with sub</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#news">sub 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#news">sub 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```